# Is there an encryption mechanism for binary data with expiration for rotating keys?

Tags: encryption, key-management, file-upload

We have a web server with an application - there is a large data array attached to the application via a mount point. We have to fulfill the requirement of securing in-transit data and at-rest data. This application is designed to host a repository of files, which are encrypted immediately post-upload, and decrypted pre-download.

The in-transit data encryption is satisfied with the use of TLS.

However, the requirements around at-rest data are a bit more stringent:

- Data must be encrypted prior to saving to filesystem
- Data must be encrypted in such a way that the stored key will expire (cannot be used to encrypt or decrypt data after xx/xx/xxxx)
- Keys must be rotated (when a key expires, it will be replaced by a new key)
- Ideally, this will be done without first decrypting the file, and then re-encrypting it with the new key.

Is there such an encryption method that will satisfy these kinds of requirements? The only two things that immediately come to my mind are x509 certificates and JWT signing (which is totally different, but similar process).

Is this even possible? I am by no means a security guru, so anything helps.

Comment: An encryption key is just some bits. A key itself does not expire. Even an expired certificate can be used since the user can simply ignore the expiration information. Thus what you want is not possible to enforce using specific keys. It is only possible to have processes around the use of keys which adhere to the restrictions you want and then declare that only these processes must be use to deal with the keys. This is similar to password policies - a password in itself does not expire, but all the processes which deal with passwords can implement policies to enforce password expiration.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Time-limited encryption](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/183367/), [Expiring Decryption Key](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/43761/), [Expiring AES Key](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/60965/).

Answer (score 2):

> Ideally, this will be done without first decrypting the file, and then re-encrypting it with the new key.

This part, at least, is easy. Each item, when uploaded, gets a symmetric (e.g. AES) "item encryption key" (IEK) that is unique, totally random, and never stored in plain text anywhere at all (except in RAM and CPU registers while encrypting or decrypting). The item is encrypted with that IEK, and then the IEK is itself encrypted (or "wrapped") with the rotating key that is common to multiple items. The wrapped IEK is stored persistently, along with the encrypted item. This way, when you need to rotate keys, you just decrypt the IEKs with the old rotating key, and re-encrypt them with the new one, and overwrite the old wrapped IEKs in storage. This approach is widely used for encrypting data at rest (e.g. encrypted files, storage volumes, databases, data within databases, password vaults, email and chat message histories, etc.).

However, as the comments under your question point out, there is no technical solution in the world for expiring a key such that it can't be used anymore. A key is just a series of bits, or a really big number if you prefer; cryptography is just doing complicated math with it. Similarly, JWTs and X.509 certs don't actually expire in any technical sense; they have a "not valid after" field, but it's up to whatever is consuming them (the validating server, or the TCP client, or whatever) to know the current date+time correctly, to check it against the JWT/cert, and *to decide what to do with the result*. If the validating party has the wrong time info, or fails to do that check correctly, or wants to ignore the result, it can still accept the JWT or cert. **As a practical matter** the validating party generally won't do that, because it's trying to protect itself; it's not the attacker, and the attacker does not get to decide. But that isn't always the case. For example, it's entirely possible to use the public key from an expired cert to verify a signature that was created using the corresponding private key. It doesn't even matter whether the cert was already expired when the private key was used, or not. Similarly, it's entirely possible for an attacker to use a key you've already rotated out to decrypt data.

You can, of course, put *policy* barriers in place. They can even be implemented in software (this is, after all, what's going on when a browser refuses to accept a server's expired TLS cert, or a server refuses to accept a client's expired JWT). But the bits themselves are still there, and can still be used for the complicated math.